# How to fix this

Tags: python-3.x

This code is supposed to find all the primes in a given range. But something is very wrong here

```
import math
def display(num, truth):
    if truth:
        print(num)

lower = int(input("Enter lower limit :"))
upper = int(input("Enter upper limit :"))
for x in range(lower, upper, 1):
    b = 2
    c = True
    a = math.sqrt(x)
    while b < a:
        if x%b != 0:
            continue
        else:
            c = False
            break
     display(x,c)
print("Done")
```

I expect that it should output, say between 2 and 6:

```
Enter lower limit :2
 Enter upper limit :6
 2
 3
 5
 Done
```

But the output is (for same range)

```
     Enter lower limit :2
     Enter upper limit :6
     2
     3
     4
```

Note that 'Done' does not appear
And when I try to close the shell Python warns that the program is still running.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand some of the code you have written.
How About something like this:

```
import math

lower = int(input("Enter lower limit :"))
upper = int(input("Enter upper limit :"))
for x in range(lower,upper + 1):
   # prime numbers are greater than 1
   if x > 1:
       for i in range(2,x):
           if (x % i) == 0:
               break
       else:
           print(x)
print("Done")
```